# Uso de plantillas personalizadas con botón de ejecución en Office 365 en la nube

Tags: macros, office365

tengo el siguiente problema:

Creé una plantilla personalizada con un botón en Word 2019
[image: Botón que controla la ejecución de la macro]

Pero cuando se carga en Office 365 en la nube, los menues y botones de acción rápida de Word no aparecen, hay alguna manera de acceder a estos en Office 365 en la nube? O alguna alternativa posible?

Gracias anticipadas compañeros

Comment: Parece que la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con temas de programación.

Comment: ES programación VBA en MS Word,